# How to place the Groovy in centralized Groovy Library and access that class from any script

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

I have the below Groovy script which i need to place it in centralized Groovy Library and then access the class mentioned in the Groovy from any script in my Ready API Project
**Path**: D:\GroovyLib\com\Linos\readyapi\util\property\propertyvalidation

```
//Change the name of the Properties test step below
def step = context.testCase.testSteps['Properties']

//Parse the xml like you have in your script
def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)

//Get the all the error details from the response as map
def errorDetails = parsedXml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'IntegrationServiceErrorCode'}.inject([:]){map, entry ->    map[entry.ErrorCode.text()] = entry.Description.text(); map    }
log.info "Error details from response  : ${errorDetails}"

def failureMessage = new StringBuffer()

//Loop thru properties of Property step and check against the response
step.properties.keySet().each { key ->
   if (errorDetails.containsKey(key)) {
       step.properties[key]?.value == errorDetails[key] ?:  failureMessage.append("Response error code discription mismatch. expected [${step.properties[key]?.value}] vs actual [${errorDetails[key]}]")
   } else {
       failureMessage.append("Response does not have error code ${key}")
   }
}
if (failureMessage.toString()) {
  throw new Error(failureMessage.toString())
}
```

I have created the code in Library as below:

```
package com.Linos.readyapi.util.property.propertyvalidation
import com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject
import groovy.sql.Sql

class PropertyValidation
{
    def static propertystepvalidation()
{
//Change the name of the Properties test step below
def step = context.testCase.testSteps['Properties']

//Parse the xml like you have in your script
def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)

//Get the all the error details from the response as map
def errorDetails = parsedXml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'IntegrationServiceErrorCode'}.inject([:]){map, entry ->    map[entry.ErrorCode.text()] = entry.Description.text(); map    }
log.info "Error details from response  : ${errorDetails}"

def failureMessage = new StringBuffer()

//Loop thru properties of Property step and check against the response
step.properties.keySet().each { key ->
   if (errorDetails.containsKey(key)) {
       step.properties[key]?.value == errorDetails[key] ?:  failureMessage.append("Response error code discription mismatch. expected [${step.properties[key]?.value}] vs actual [${errorDetails[key]}]")
   } else {
       failureMessage.append("Response does not have error code ${key}")
   }
}
if (failureMessage.toString()) {
  throw new Error(failureMessage.toString())
}
```

I am not sure what to mention in the def static method. I am new to this process and haven't done that yet. Can someone please guide me! I've read the documentation on Ready API! website. But I'm not clear on that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Ready API but can't you simply add it to your classpath?

Comment: No.. this is our client need.. Trying to replicate the process mentioned in the below website. http://readyapi.smartbear.com/features/scripts/library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ReadyAPI allows users to create libraries and put them under `Script` directory and reuse them as needed.

Please note that, ReadyAPI does not allow to have a groovy script in the `Script` directory, instead it should be Groovy classes.

Looks you were trying to convert a script, answered from one of the previous questions, to class.

Here there are certain variables available in Groovy Script by SoapUI. So, those needs to passed to library class. For instance, `context, log` are common.

And there can be some more parameters related to your method as well. In this case, you need to pass the `file, property step name` etc.

Here is the Groovy Class which isconverted from the script. And the method can be non-static or static. But I go with non-static.

```
package com.Linos.readyapi.util.property.propertyvalidation

class PropertyValidator {

    def context
    def log

    def validate(String stepName, File file) {
        //Change the name of the Properties test step below
        def step = context.testCase.testSteps[stepName]

        //Parse the xml like you have in your script
        def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)

        //Get the all the error details from the response as map
        def errorDetails = parsedXml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'IntegrationServiceErrorCode'}.inject([:]){map, entry ->    map[entry.ErrorCode.text()] = entry.Description.text(); map    }
        log.info "Error details from response  : ${errorDetails}"

        def failureMessage = new StringBuffer()

        //Loop thru properties of Property step and check against the response
        step.properties.keySet().each { key ->
            if (errorDetails.containsKey(key)) {
                step.properties[key]?.value == errorDetails[key] ?:  failureMessage.append("Response error code discription mismatch. expected [${step.properties[key]?.value}] vs actual [${errorDetails[key]}]")
            } else {
                failureMessage.append("Response does not have error code ${key}")
            }
        }
        if (failureMessage.toString()) {
            throw new Error(failureMessage.toString())
        } 
    }
}
```

Hope you already aware where to copy the above class. Note that this also has package name. So copy it in the right directory. 
I have suggestion here regarding your package name which is so long, you can change it to something like `com.linos.readyapi.util`. Of course, upto you.

Now here is how you can use / call the above class or its methods from a `Groovy Script` test step of a test case in the different soapui projects:

**Groovy Script step**

```
import com.Linos.readyapi.util.property.propertyvalidation.PropertyValidator

def properties = [context:context, log:log] as PropertyValidator
//You need to have the file object here
properties.validate('Properties', file)
```

Comment: Thanks @Rao.. Well drafted answer and i clearly understand.. It works:) 
As usual you rocked:):)

Comment: @Harry, glad it helped.

Comment: Can you please explain what this statement infers?
**def properties = [context:context, log:log] as PropertyValidator**

Comment: Not clear, which statement? May you can http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140141/soapui

Comment: It is just instantiating class with argument, like how you were trying to do, but in a different way(map as your class). It is possible to create an object of class differently in groovy. Please refer [documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html)

Comment: yeah.. Thank You! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ah! a utility library you mean?
Assuming you have placed your groovy library file in this path

> D:\GroovyLib\com\Linos\readyapi\util\property\propertyvalidation

If you are using soapui then set above path as the value of below field,

> File>preferences>SoapUiPro>Script Library

If you are using ready api then,

> File>preferences>Ready! API>Script Library

Then call your method by initializing the class first

```
PropertyValidation classObject = new PropertyValidation()
classObject.propertystepvalidation()
//you might need to pass some parameters which are declared/initiated outside this class
```